# Задать условие как переменную, которую можно достать и применить из элемента класса

Tags: python

Создаю класс правило: оно состоит из набора условий и значения, которое нужно достать из правила, если условия правила выполнены

Например

1. Правило 1: если у человека 1 рука и он из Москвы, верни 1
2. Правило 2: если у человека 2 руки и он из Москвы, верни 2

Для каждого человека с его набором правил нужно будет вывести актуальное для него правило
хочу потом легко создать новое правило с его набором условий без переписывания всего кода

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример когда из двух правил создаётся одно новое. Как это выглядит?

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Answer (score 0):

Честно, максимально непонятный вопрос, но я думаю это выглядит так:

```
class Test:
    def rule1(self):
        print(1)
    def rule2(self):
        print(2)

while True:
    hands = int(input('Сколько у вас рук?'))
    moscow = input('Вы из москвы? yes/no')
    if hands == 1 and moscow == 'yes':
        Test().rule1()
    if hands == 2 and moscow == 'yes':
        Test().rule2()
    if moscow.lower() == 'exit':
        exit()
```

Comment: в последствии просто добавлять методы для новых правил